# TypeError: r is not a function next-auth with nextJs

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, next-auth

I am getting this error after I installed `next-auth`. Any idea what this is?

```
TypeError: r is not a function
    at /Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63257
    at /Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:133:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at /Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:56774
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Object.wrap (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:37057)
    at /Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54547
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Object.wrap (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:36306)
    at /Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54509


    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at eH.execute (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53902)
    at eH.handle (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:64515)
    at doRender (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1330:60)
    at cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1540:46)
    at ResponseCache.get (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:49:26)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/Users/eme/Desktop/CODING PROJECTS/sponsonex-ui/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1460:53)
```

I deleted my `node-modules` and reinstalled but still getting the same error. This is `nextAuth` beta.